# Passing Tuple into __init__ in Python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

I have a class like this.

```
class AddNoteForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, test_values, *args):
        self.custom_choices = test_values
        super(AddNoteForm, self).__init__()
        self.fields['choices'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label='Test Choices', choices=self.custom_choices)
```

I'd like to pass this tuple during class creation.

```
test_values = (
    ('name1', 'value1'), 
    ('name2', 'value2'),
    ('name3', 'value3'),
)

form = AddNoteForm(test_values)
```

But whenever I do so, I get a `__init__() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)`
 error. I'm also using python 2.7 (and Django 1.8).

I look at the variables in the debug page and self.custom_choices contain the right values (test_values that I passed into the function).

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the method signature for `forms.Form`, from which `AddNoteForm` inherits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ModelMultipleChoiceField is expecting a queryset as its first parameter (following self).  What you want here is a regular MultipleChoiceField.

I also threw in the passing of args/kwargs to the superclass **init**, which is a good practice since forms can take a lot of useful parameters, such as 'initial', that you might want to use some time, and then it'll drive you nuts when it doesn't work...

```
class AddNoteForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, test_values, *args, **kwargs):
        self.custom_choices = test_values
        super(AddNoteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choices'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
          label='Test Choices',
          choices=self.custom_choices
        )
```